# the logic in the word weekender?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

'Weekender', term used to refer to a person who spends time in a particular place only on weekends. does that make sense to have the 'er' attached to the word 'weekend' to form this train of thought?

Comment: A 'weekend' is a period of time, and a 'weekender' is a person whose activity is related to that. Similarly for many nouns or verbs: a biker spends time on a bike, etc.

Comment: The full OED also lists several more meanings for this same "derived" noun - 1) A recreational or **leisure event**, such as a short holiday, a party, etc., taking place over a weekend, 2) A **holiday home**, esp. for use at the weekend, 3) A **bag or case** suitable for carrying everything needed for a weekend away from home; a weekend bag, 4) A **small pleasure boat**, esp. for use at the weekend, and 5) A **person who uses recreational drugs** occasionally, esp. at the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it makes sense - '*-er*' is a very common suffix for verbs to denote someone who carries out that action (for example, *teacher, trainer, writer*) or for something that causes an action (for example, *thriller, chiller, amplifier*)

'Weekend' is of course a noun, not a verb - but you can appreciate that, from the perspective of those in the tourism industry, visiting or coming (both verbs) for the weekend is something noteworthy, so it isn't surprising that 'weekender' has come to mean someone who visits for the weekend.